# Is the colllection of all open 'squares' and all open 'rectangles' a basis for euclidean topology on $\Bbb R^2$?

Tags: general-topology

Is the colllection of all open 'squares' and all open 'rectangles'  a basis for euclidean topology on $\Bbb R^2$

Comment: What are your taughts? What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.